# Bootstrap function throwing error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Tags: angular, gulp

After a few days debugging my code so that gulp can at last build it, my main.ts looks like this:

```
   ///<reference path="../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />

//main entry point
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {App} from './app';
import {MATERIAL_PROVIDERS} from "ng2-material/all";
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

  bootstrap(App, [MATERIAL_PROVIDERS], [HTTP_PROVIDERS])
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

I'm getting the following error: `src\main.ts(9,1): error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.`

I can't figure out why this, that has been copied from the old tour of heroes guide, and is in itself pretty simple, is giving me such an error. I'm trying to look for the old bootstrap function since maybe I'm using it wrong (this code works on plunker, so I'm not sure if that could be the case), and I'm not sure if I'm even looking at the right place.

Anyone mind helping me out? I'm on beta.8 version and using gulp to transpile.

Gulp.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    traceur = require('gulp-traceur'),
    webserver = require('gulp-webserver')
    typescript = require('gulp-typescript');

// run init tasks
gulp.task('default', ['dependencies', 'ts', 'js', 'html', 'css']);

// run development task
gulp.task('dev', ['watch', 'serve']);

// serve the build dir
gulp.task('serve', function () {
  gulp.src('build')
    .pipe(webserver({
      open: true,
      port: 8070
    }));
});

// watch for changes and run the relevant task
gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('src/**/*.ts', ['ts']);
  gulp.watch('src/**/*.js', ['js']);
  gulp.watch('src/**/*.html', ['html']);
  gulp.watch('src/**/*.css', ['css']);
});

// move dependencies into build dir
gulp.task('dependencies', function () {
  return gulp.src([
    'node_modules/traceur/bin/traceur-runtime.js',
    'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-csp-production.src.js',
    'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js',
    'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
    'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js',
    'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js',
    'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js',
    'node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js',
    'node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.map'
  ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/lib'));
});

gulp.task('ts', function () {
  return gulp.src(['src/**/*.ts', 'node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts'])
          .pipe(typescript(
            {
                "target": "es5",
                "module": "system",
                "moduleResolution": "node",
                "sourceMap": true,
                "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
                "experimentalDecorators": true,
                "removeComments": false,
                "noImplicitAny": false
            }))
          .pipe(gulp.dest('src'));
});

// transpile & move js
gulp.task('js', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/**/*.js')
    .pipe(rename({
      extname: ''
    }))
    .pipe(traceur({
      modules: 'instantiate',
      moduleName: true,
      annotations: true,
      types: true,
      memberVariables: true
    }))
    .pipe(rename({
      extname: '.js'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/src'));
});

// move html
gulp.task('html', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/**/*.html')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
});

// move css
gulp.task('css', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/**/*.css')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/src'))
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`bootstrap(App, [MATERIAL_PROVIDERS, HTTP_PROVIDERS] /* method accepts just one array !? */)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));`

Comment: I can't freaking believe it. That does work. I really fail to understand why when I try stuff on plunker and on the browser it runs then I go local and everything fails. Thanks A LOT, you saved me. I accept as soon as 10 minutes pass by. Btw, is there any place where I can check this? I really fail to look for official documentation of older versions :/

Comment: yw! :) i am not sure.. the URL looks like it could be possible: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html (see the latest) .. but i dont know if and how to view older documentations, sorry.